# How to use SymPy Plot3d while the coordinates range has correlation

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I am drawing a 3d plotting with SymPy Plot3D

```
plot3d(expr, (x,-1,1), (y,-1,1))
```

It seems the range of x and y are specified independently.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
plot3d(expr, (x,-1,1), (y,x**2,1))
```

that is, y range from x**2 to 1.

Anyway to do that?

### Update

Suppose I will do the plot as a Parametric Surface. How to convert my surface from the form:

> z=f(x,y)
>
> where x= [-1, +1],  y= [x*x, 1]

into a parameterized form?

Answer (score 0):

The way you suggest will not work with sympy. However you can use a Piecewise function or a logical function or Heaviside or something similar that is zero out of the region of interest and just multiply your expression by it.

However the appropriate way to do this, instead of the hack above, would be to change the parametrization of your surface and just use parametric 3d plot. It would look much nicer.